# Set histogram ticks/label using Syntax

Tags: data-visualization, spss

Let me preface this by saying that I am a programmer by trade, but not very familiar with SPSS.

I am helping a friend set up some histogram plots using SPSS Syntax language. Using the Chart Builder, we have arrived at the code below:

```
GGRAPH
  /GRAPHDATASET NAME="graphdataset" VARIABLES=OurVariable MISSING=LISTWISE REPORTMISSING=NO
  /GRAPHSPEC SOURCE=INLINE
  TEMPLATE=[
    "C:\some\path\greenHistogram.sgt"].
BEGIN GPL
  SOURCE: s=userSource(id("graphdataset"))
  DATA: OurVariable=col(source(s), name("OurVariable"))
  GUIDE: axis(dim(1), label("OurVariable"))
  GUIDE: axis(dim(2), label("Frequency"))
  GUIDE: text.title(label("Bla bla",
    "bla"))
  ELEMENT: interval(position(summary.count(bin.rect(OurVariable, binStart(0.5)))),
    shape.interior(shape.square))
END GPL.
```

As you can see, she would like to make the histogram columns green. We could not achieve that using the Chart Builder, but we could easily make a template via the Chart Editor window and apply that. This seems like a very sensible approach, as she has many charts she wants green.

She would also like to customize the y-axis labels (number of decimal places, tick "major increment" etc.). This can also be achieved using the Chart Editor and saving a template. However, this is a much more individualized edit, and making a custom template for each and every plot seems cumbersome. Is it possible to adjust these things directly in the Syntax-script which generates the plots?

In many other places there is a nice Paste-button which generates the necessacy code, but I could not find one in the Chart Editor.

Comment: I've voted as off-topic and to migrate to stack overflow. Tick major increment is an option when generating the bins, see `binStart` and `binWidth` in the [GPL reference](ftp://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/analytics/spss/documentation/statistics/22.0/en/client/Manuals/GPL_Reference_Guide_for_IBM_SPSS_Statistics.pdf).